# Global low-level mouse hook doesn't get called when UWP desktop app is out of focus

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm creating a desktop UWP app and I need to set a global low level mouse hook to detect and change the position of it when it is moved to certain locations of the screen.

It works fine while my app's window is in focus and the values get logged correctly to the output window(meaning that the hook is working correctly).

This UWP app isn't going to be on the store and will only be used on a Windows 10 desktop (1903+).

I've tried calling `SetWindowsHookEx` on a different thread (which didn't do anything).
Tried also passing a thread ID when calling `SetWindowsHookEx` to no avail.
Also tried using the following restricted capabilities to prevent the app to suspend when not on focus: `extendedExecutionUnconstrained` and `extendedBackgroundTaskTime` along with the `PreventFromSuspending` method shown [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2018/01/30/non-suspending-uwp-desktop-apps/).
Another thing I tried was to set `uiAccess` to true on the app manifest, which also didn't work.

The global hook is supposed to work even when the app isn't in the foreground, but instead it just works when it has the active window focus.

```cs
#region Structures

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
/* MSLLHOOKSTRUCT */
public struct NativeMouseLowLevelHook
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{nameof(Point)}: {Point}, {nameof(MouseData)}: {MouseData}, {nameof(Flags)}: {Flags}";
    }

    public NativePoint Point;
    public int MouseData;
    public int Flags;
    public int Time;
    public UIntPtr ExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class NativePoint
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{nameof(X)}: {X}, {nameof(Y)}: {Y}";
    }

    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

#endregion
#region Hook

public class ManagedMouseHook : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    public static List<ManagedMouseHook> KnownHooks { get; set; } = new List<ManagedMouseHook>();

    public HookProc HookImpl { get; set; }

    public ManagedMouseHook() : base(true)
    {
        Hook();
    }

    private void Hook()
    {
        HookImpl = NativeHookCallback;
        KnownHooks.Add(this);
        using (var curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (var curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            DoHook(curModule);
        }
    }

    private void DoHook(ProcessModule curModule)
    {
        SetHandle(SetWindowsHookEx(14 /*WH_MOUSE_LL*/, HookImpl, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0));
    }

    private bool UnHook()
    {
        var result = UnhookWindowsHookEx(DangerousGetHandle());
        KnownHooks.Remove(this);
        HookImpl = null;
        return result;
    }

    /* LowLevelMouseProc */
    private IntPtr NativeHookCallback(int code, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
    {
        if (code >= 0)
        {
            var info = (NativeMouseLowLevelHook) Marshal.PtrToStructure(lparam,
                typeof(NativeMouseLowLevelHook));

            Debug.WriteLine(info); //Output example: Point: X: 408, Y: 535, MouseData: 0, Flags: 0
            return new IntPtr(-1);
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, code, wparam, lparam);
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return UnHook();
    }
}

#endregion
#region Interop

public delegate IntPtr HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int hookType, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, ulong dwThreadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam,
    IntPtr lParam);

#endregion
```

Then, to start using it:

```cs
public ManagedMouseHook MouseHook { get; set; }
```

```cs
MouseHook/*property*/ = new ManagedMouseHook();
```

And to unhook:

```cs
MouseHook/*property*/.Close();
```

Comment: SetWindowsHookEx is dramatically incompatible with Microsoft's reasons for implementing UWP.  Old cruft, endless problems, don't call me when it doesn't work.  The different integrity levels (think UAC) are the way they put their foot down on stopping the practice.

Comment: So there's no way to reliably detect global mouse movement without having a timer checking for `CoreWindow.PointerPosition`?

Comment: Nobody could possibly guess why you can't see mouse movement in your own window.  Somebody else's window, no.  Classic SO mistake, you only talked about what you thought might work without describing the problem you need to solve.

Comment: @HansPassant The mouse hook works fine when my app's window is in focus. Changed the post a bit to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided with the help of the comments that the best way to do this is to use my UWP app as a front-end and using a win32 app for the hooking functionality itself.

Answer (score 1):

UWP apps are running in the sandbox, so that doesn't sound strange. If you think a bit it is a security problem if the app can receive such an input and as 'Security' is listed as No.1 characteristic of the UWP this behavior is expected.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll just move over to WPF :(
Decided to use UWP mainly for the Fluent Design. I guess it's a lost cause.

Comment: @NickAc that being said, you may have a Win32 component in the UWP package and it may then communicate to UWP app. That could work, haven’t tried and may be too complicated to handle, but you can try that.

Comment: Won't that win32 component also run inside the sandbox?

Comment: I guess I could hand over the hooking stuff to a deamon app and use the UWP for user configuration only.

Comment: This sounds feasible. You can use a Win32 app to implement your functionality, and write a UWP app as a front-end to display, then use the desktop bridge to package them into a whole UWP app.

Comment: @NickAc Win32 component will run in a sandbox, but it is not as restricted as UWP. Mostly it can't write the real registry.